# Does each webcontainer require its own servlet implementation?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

We usually get a servlet-api.jar along with web/app server.

- Does each one have its own implementation of servlet JSR or will they use SUN provided API?
- Is this applicable to all other J2EE API's (EJB, JMS, MAIL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like as the remnant of the whole Java EE API, the Servlet API is **abstract**. <s>Sun</s> Oracle doesn't provide any code. The contract is definied on paper ([API specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html), [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html), etc). The implementors have to provide the **concrete** API and implementation themselves which comply the specs/javadocs. But there's usually a so called "reference implementation" whose code may be shared/reused/forked for other implementations. Until with Servlet 2.5, this used to be Apache Tomcat. For Servlet 3.0 this is Glassfish.

Comment: I don't like the strike-through :P :) also, I think they do provide the interfaces in one jar, don't they? (+1)

Comment: @Bozho: Me neither :) The interface classes (no source files!) were only public availabe until with version 2.2. See also [this archive](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/reference/api/index.html).